# is this a mistake or am I missing something?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

In my material, I saw this:
let there be $a_n$ a sequence such that $lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = L$ and $b_n=\frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^n a_j $, prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty}b_n=L$
and it was proven like this: Let ther be $\epsilon \gt 0$ we choose $N_0$ such that for every $n\gt N_0$ such that $\vert a_n - L\vert \lt \frac\epsilon 2$ then :
$$\vert b_n-L\vert\leq\frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n \vert a_j-L\vert\leq\frac1n \sum_{j=1}^{N_0} \vert a_j-L\vert+\frac1n \sum_{j=N_0+1}^n \frac\epsilon 2$$
now if we define $M_0=\frac1n \sum_{j=1}^{N_0} \vert a_j-L\vert$ then we get $\vert b_n-L\vert\leq\frac {M_0} n + \frac\epsilon2$ for every $n\gt N_0$ and we coose $N_1$ such that for every $n\gt N_1$ such that $\frac {M_0} n\lt \frac \epsilon 2$ then choose $N_\epsilon = (N_0,N_1)$ and we're done. my question is about this part $$\vert b_n-L\vert\leq\frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n \vert a_j-L\vert$$ shouldn't it be $$\vert b_n-L\vert\leq\vert(\frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n  a_j)-L\vert$$

Answer (score 1):

Simple algebra shows:

\begin{align}
\vert b_n-L\vert&=\vert(\frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n  a_j)-L\vert\\
&=\vert(\frac1n \sum_{j=1}^n  a_j)-\frac 1n \sum_{j=1}^nL\vert\\
&=\frac 1n\vert\sum_{j=1}^n  (a_j-L)\vert \\
&\leq \frac 1n\sum_{j=1}^n  |a_j-L|.
\end{align}